# Excel: Create Validation List from Filtered values in column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've been trying to find a way of doing this with dependent dropdowns, but I am yet to be successful with my specific tables. In essence I'm looking to create a validation list based on a "filtered" results list from another table.

These are structured tables:

**Table1** (with static values to be "filtered" )

```
id      Items
2       ItemAA
2       ItemAAA
3       ItemZZ
5       ItemXY
5       ItemXYZ
2       ItemCC
```

**Table2 (With the Validation List dropdown)**

```
idFromTable1  RelatedOptionFromFilteredDropdownList
2             ItemAA  (dropdown lists: ItemAA, ItemAAA, ItemCC)
5             ItemXY  (dropdown lists: ItemXY, ItemXYZ)
2             ItemCC  (dropdown lists: ItemAA, ItemAAA, ItemCC)
3             ItemZZ  (dropdown lists: ItemZZ)
```

*Edit*: using formulas, not VBA

*Edit2*: Both ID and Items will be counted on the hundreds or thousands.

Thank you

Comment: The thing is that I don't know where to start with this, specifically with how to create that "filtered list" within the validation list formula.It's one thing to return a single text value, there's a lot of options for that, but I haven't found how to return a vector with the multiple filtered values.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a named list

1. First, sort your **Table1** by ID
2. Create a named range with the name `listlookup` (or whatever).
3. Put this formula on the `listlookup`

`=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address", INDEX($B$2:$B$5, MATCH($C1, $A$2:$A$5, 0)))), 0, 0, COUNTIF($A$2:$A$5, $C1), 1)`

```
 ID | Items   | lookup_value_here | dropdown_list_here
 1  | ItemXY
 1  | ItemXYZ
 2  | ItemZ
 2  | ItemZZ
```

4. Create the drop down list, and refer the list to `listlookup`

### Explanation

`INDEX($B$2:$B$5, MATCH($C1, $A$2:$A$5, 0))` finds the first cell that has the `lookup_value`

`CELL( ... )` returns the string referring to the cell (for example: `$B$2` for `lookup_value` 1)

`INDIRECT( ... )` converts the string reference to cell reference

`OFFSET( ... , 0, 0, ... , 1)` returns the range from the lookup (for example: `B2:B3` for `lookup_value` 1)

`COUNTIF( ... )` returns the number of data matching the `lookup_value`

---

This is fun, because I've stumbled into this problem in the past and can't solve it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is the method how you do any dependent validation list, as far as I can see. In any case, it's impossible because there can be thousands of options in the ID field...

Comment: Updated answer. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the followup. Although this is more comprehensive, I can't seem to use it as a validation List, only on a cell while issuing CSE, which returns just the first value. I guess the validation list would require an array result. I found another question where I think the issue was the same as mine but in the end I can't use the named range in the validation list, it returns a blank list. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803196/excel-array-formula-as-name-range-not-working

Comment: The `OFFSET` returns array. The formula is intended to be used in `name manager`, and called in the data validation, not entered in the worksheet as array formula. Can you elaborate more, or give a screenshot of your result?

Comment: Ok, I've reviewed what I was doing and got it working like your example. And though it is a significant step, I still have to check if I can make your `dropdown_list_here` field run for every line of a given table. But the one big issue I have right now is that there is no way I can have the table sorted as you mention right on the first step.